# What happens when an electron has a positive value of energy and it is in a square well finite potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

We know that in a finite square well potential like this one [image], when an electron has less energy than 0 (its energy is between 0 and -V0), it will be bound in the well. If I have an electron in the well with an energy greater than 0, will it be bound? If yes, why and how? if no, why and how? (I'm speaking in terms of quantum physics and not classical physics)

Comment: the electron is not bound.  I don't know how to answer the "why" other than to say that a bound state will have $E<0$ in a finite well.

Comment: but the well has at least one bound state, you are saying that the well does not retain at all the electron in one of its bound state?

Comment: yes but the bound state has negative energy.

Comment: Could you explain how an electron would act in the well in this particular situation, I just have difficulties visualizing it, I also don't understand your last response. I'm beginning to study this matter so don't hesitate to explain it as if I had little knowledge about the subject.

Comment: The electron would not stay in the well if $E>0$ since there is no bound state with $E>0$.